# Events not triggering on some Samsung devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, samsung-mobile

I am facing jQuery issues for text fields on Samsung devices. One of the issues is I am continuously typing the text in text field some times jQuery is not working in samsung devices like the Galaxy Tab and the Galaxy S3.

```
<div class="holder">Email Address </div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" maxlength="45" value="" >
```

```css
.holder {
    position: absolute;
    padding:4% ; 
    color: #7f8184;
    font-size:1.813em;
    font-style:italic;
    cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
    cursor:-webkit-zoom-out;
    cursor:-webkit-zoom-grab;
    cursor:-webkit-zoom-grabbing ;
}
```

```js
$("form input").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        $(this).prev('.holder').hide();
    } else {
        $(this).prev('.holder').show();
    }
    $(this).on('input', function() {
        if ($(this).val() || $(this).text().length > 0) {
            $(this).prev('.holder').hide();
        } else {
            $(this).prev('.holder').show();
        }
    });
    $(".holder").click(function() {
        $(this).next().focus();
    });
});
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thiru715/g263W/1/)</kbd>

major issue i notice is when running javascript, weird things happen. For example, on form submit, i want place placeholder. Usually, a simple jquery did the job and works well on desktop browser, including the mobile chrome browser, but not in the stock browser(Samsung default browers). after entering some characters the browser just stop all javascript processing.
any one facing this issue...

Comment: Try using `keypress` instead of `input`.

Comment: Thanks for reply,
In a text field i am entering the 40 or 35 characters continuously  its stop's triggering jquery in samsung mobile or tab default browsers.
up to 35 or 40 characters working fine.
If you also got this road block you have at-least 3 test fields in a form. 
Other browser's work's fine.

Answer (score 0):

After i update to  http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
my problem resolved